# Why can't I initialize this socket?

Tags: android, sockets, permissions

I keep getting the following error:

```
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: 
EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I've searched multiple links online and I can't find a solution to let me initialize a new DatagramSocket to open a local socket.  Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.upnext.upnext">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
```

EDIT: Maybe this helps, this is where I declare the socket:

```
int portNumber = 5000;
String ipAddress = "0.0.0.0";

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(portNumber);
```

Comment: Is it possible you are attempting to bind to a port number below 1024?

Comment: `Here is my manifest:` ?? We expected: 'Here is my code:'.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.  I included it in the above post.  No I am using port #5000